# existence of integer in some expression

Tags: number-theory

Given integers $c_2$ and $d_2$ (not both zero), and $m$, (divisible by a prime number $p$, i.e. $m=n\cdot p, n \in \mathbb{N}$)

We want to find integers $c_1$ and $d_1$ such that $c_1 \cdot c_2 + d_1 \cdot d_2 \cdot m - 1 =  p \cdot q\ , \ q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

I tried to write it as $c_1 \cdot c_2 + d_1 \cdot d_2 \cdot m - 1 = p \cdot [\frac{(c_1 \cdot c_2 - 1)}{p} + d_1 \cdot d_2 \cdot (\frac{m}{p})$].

Since p divides m, $d_1 \cdot d_2 \cdot (\frac{m}{p})$ is integral. But I am unable to show that the first term is also an integer.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: No, take $c_2=p$.